# Retrieve Data from Network thread android

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, network-programming

I am trying to get a JSON ARRAY  from A URL to a android app and I have created network connection in a special thread. my connection works fine but I cannot parse the receiving data to a string variable my connection class as follows

```
public class Connection {

    String data="no data";

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    Context mContext;
    public Connection(Context context){
        this.mContext=context;
    }


  public void runNetwork(String url) {
        final String urlString = url;

        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()  {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                    String NetworkData = convertStreamToString(stream);
                   System.out.println(NetworkData);
                    setData(NetworkData);
                    stream.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();



    }
    static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }

}
```

when I print networkData variable it prints data retrieve from url. But its not parsing outside the thread.What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Would be easier if you just use OkHttp. :)

Comment: there is nothing wrong, actually it definitely does what you say but not at the same time as you think. if you try waiting for a few secs on the main thread before printing it out, you will see that it's all ok.